# Installing `lsp-mode` and `dap-mode` from melpa

Tags: lsp-mode, dap

When I install `lsp-mode` from Melpa, I get version 20221003.1714.

When I install `dap-mode` from Melpa, I get version 20220921.941, which requires `lsp-mode-6.0`.

As a result, `(require 'dap-mode)` fails:

```
Unable to activate package ‘dap-mode’.
Required package ‘lsp-mode-6.0’ is unavailable
```

When I look inside `lsp-mode.el`, I see

```
;; Version: 8.0.1
```

Looking at this, it appears that I am getting a snapshot version of `lsp-mode` which is based on a higher version than `dap-mode` requires.  But something in the package framework is not figuring out the versions.

The only solution that I am seeing is to clone the `lsp-mode` repo, checkout a release tag and manually add it to my class-path. I'm guessing that would work, but it would make getting updates much harder.

Is there a resolution to this?  When I do `package-list-packages`, I don't see a version of `lsp-mode` with a fixed version number to install.

*package-archives*:

package-archives is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.
Its value is
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
Original value was
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))

*Emacs version*:

GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, NS appkit-2022.60 Version 11.6.4 (Build 20G417))
of 2022-03-02

Comment: What's the *question*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling both `lsp-mode` and `dap-mode`. Then install `dap-mode` allowing the package system to pull in the `lsp-mode` dependency automatically. When I did that I got:

```
dap-mode   20220921.941   installed    Debug Adapter Protocol mode
lsp-mode   20220815.958   installed    LSP mode
```

At that point `(require 'dap-mode)` *worksforme*.

Comment: I was using `cask` and `pallet` for package management, and for some reason, my Cask file was explicitly requiring lip-mode 6.0.  When I uninstalled enough stuff and deleted the version locks, it worked for me too.